# Docker: Why does --rm does not remove my container as I exit from it

Tags: docker

I'm running Docker on Windows10.

adding --rm to a docker container run command should remove my container as I exit from it, but since a while, if I type

```
docker container run -p 80:80 --rm nginx
```

I get

```
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Enabled listen on IPv6 in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
```

and nginx runs well on my docker-machine IP address, but then if I type

```
ctrl+C
```

and I check my conainers with `docker container ls` I see that container is still running:

```
$ docker container ls
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                NAMES
012963897aa4        nginx               "/docker-entrypoint.…"   2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp   affectionate_dhawan
```

Why?

Comment: `--rm` only takes effect when the container is _stopped_. There's no surprise that `--rm` doesn't delete a container that's still running (just because you detached from having its logs written to your console).

Comment: How do I prevent having its log written to the console?

Comment: So you're asking how to start a container in the background, without ever interactively displaying its log? `docker container start` I'd expect.

Comment: I have explained my doubt in another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67392324/docker-container-run-returns-no-more-the-generated-container-id-but-its-logs

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> adding `--rm` to a docker container run command should remove my container **as I exit from it**.

This is a misconception. The `--rm` flag tells Docker to remove the container **when it stops**.

I see you passed no extra flags to your `docker container run` command, so I'll assume you *attach* to your container after starting it. **Detaching from a container does not stop it automatically**, unless the container is started with the `-i` flag, which should automatically attach stdin/stdout to the container with that run command.

To remove a container that was started with `--rm` flag, you cam simply `docker stop` it and it'll be gone.