# 'Docker container run' returns no more the generated container ID but its logs

Tags: docker

I am newby doing experiments with docker.

Once, as I runned

```
docker container run --publish 80:80 nginx
```

I just got the generated container ID.

Then I did various things and now, as I run the same command, I get

```
$ docker container run --publish 80:80 nginx
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Enabled listen on IPv6 in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
```

Why? Is this because I am now running that same command in a different directory that has a Dockerfile?

Here is the content of the Dockerfile:

```
# this shows how we can extend/change an existing official image from Docker Hub

FROM nginx:latest
# highly recommend you always pin versions for anything beyond dev/learn

WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
# change working directory to root of nginx webhost
# using WORKDIR is preferred to using 'RUN cd /some/path'

COPY index.html index.html

# I don't have to specify EXPOSE or CMD because they're in my FROM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how you start the docker container.
The command you use will run it as foreground process and will print the stdout of the container to console (Docker default).

If you want to only see the ID and run it as background you have to add the detach option:

```
docker container run --detach --publish 80:80 nginx
docker run -d -p 80:80 nginx
```

See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#detached-vs-foreground
and https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_run/